# Is it possible to have calculations within repeat tables in Orbeon?

Tags: orbeon

I would like to collect numbers from a repeat table and have them add up to an input field later in the form. Is this possible to do?

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is possible. You can use the `sum()` function to do this, for example `sum($values)` if the repeated field is named `value`.

Comment: Even if the repeat row doesn't exist on the form when it is all built out? I see that the repeats do allow for calculations if they exist on the form, but I am curious about the scenario when a repeat row is added after the fact.

Comment: Yes, it doesn't matter when repeated rows are added.